# SQL CREATE VIEW with for in for and SELECTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, view

i´m trying to create a View in a Postgres Database with this Table:

```
|----|------|------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| id | t1_n | t2_n | value1 | value2 | value3 | valueX |
|----|------|------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 1  |  A   |  X   |   12   |    2   |   1    |   ..   |
| 2  |  B   |  Y   |   2    |    2   |   20   |   ..   |
| 3  |  C   |  Z   |   41   |    1   |   1    |   ..   |
| 4  |  A   |  Z   |   43   |    3   |   4    |   ..   |
| 5  |  B   |  Y   |   15   |    5   |   1    |   ..   |
| 6  |  C   |  X   |   52   |    2   |   5    |   ..   |
| 7  |  ..  | ..   |   ..   |   ..   |   ..   |   ..   |
|----|------|------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
```

In the view, each zone should be entered with each existing division.
The next columns contain results from individual SELECTS.

View:

```
|----|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| id | t1_n | t2_n | sum1 | sum2 | sum3 | sum4 |
|----|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 1  |  A   |  X   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 2  |  A   |  Y   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 3  |  A   |  Z   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 1  |  B   |  X   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 2  |  B   |  Y   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 3  |  B   |  Z   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 1  |  C   |  X   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 2  |  C   |  Y   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 3  |  C   |  Z   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
| 3  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |
|----|------|------|------|------|------|------|
```

sum1 should be:

```
SELECT sum(value1) FROM table1 WHERE t1_n = [current_t1_n] AND t2_n = [current_t2_n];
```

sum2 should be:

```
SELECT sum(value2) FROM table1 WHERE t1_n = [current_t1_n] AND t2_n = [current_t2_n];
```

sum3 should be:

```
SELECT sum(value3) FROM table1 WHERE t1_n = [current_t1_n] AND t2_n = [current_t2_n];
```

maybe something like that:

```
for(t1_n){
  for(t2_n){
   set sum1, sum2, sum3, sumX...}}
```

thx, for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the sums as subqueries, and join those subqueries to a list of all of the common columns.  This is an example of the pattern:

```
select
    k.t1_n,
    k.t2_n,
    sum1,
    sum2
from
    (select distinct t1_n, t2n from table1) as k
    left join (
        select t1_n, t2_n, sum(value1) as sum1
        from table1
        group by t1_n, t2_n
        ) as s1 using (t1_n, t2_n)
    left join (
        select t1_n, t2_n, sum(value2) as sum2
        from table1
        group by t1_n, t2_n
        ) as s2 using (t1_n, t2_n)
 ;
```

You will presumably want to extend this for the additional columns and sums.  If your table has no missing values, you could use inner joins instead.